# Null value if matching group does not match/work

Tags: java, regex, scala, logparser

Is any `regex` expression that return empty or null value if don't find match?

For example, I have regex which  processes this log line:

```
May  5 23:00:01 99.99.99.99 %FRA-8-333344: Built inbound UDP connection 9999888811 for outside:11.111.111.11/47747 (11.111.111.11/47747) to net-9999:22.22.22.22/53 (22.22.22.22/53)
```

But sometimes logs are different for example one value is missing (example: connection id missing):

```
May  5 23:00:01 99.99.99.99 %FRA-8-333344: Built inbound UDP for outside:11.111.111.11/47747 (11.111.111.11/47747) to net-9999:22.22.22.22/53 (22.22.22.22/53)
```

My problem is that I want to handle this change, my idea is to return empty value if `regex` don't find value.  My next step is to build hive table, for this reason values extract from `regex` must have right order, and for example UDP value cannot be written on connection id column.

Does anyone know solution of this problem? In R Language  solution is very simple (str_extract_all) and array of regex expressions, but in Scala I Can't handle..

key-values from first log:

```
timestamp: May  5 23:00:01
Action: Built
protocol: UDP
connection_id: 9999888811
src_ip: 11.111.111.11
dst_ip:  22.22.22.22
src_port  47747
dst_port 53
```

key-values from second log:

```
timestamp: May  5 23:00:01
Action: Built
protocol: UDP
connection_id: **EMPTY/NULL/" "**
src_ip: 11.111.111.11
dst_ip:  22.22.22.22
src_port  47747
dst_port 53
```

For every help I will be grateful :)

UPDATE 28.06.2017

My regex: https://regex101.com/r/4mtAtu/1

My solution. I think it will be slow:

```
case class logValues(time_stamp: String, action: String, protocol: String, connection_id: String, ips: String, ports: String)


def matchLog(x: String): logValues = {

  val time_stamp =  """^.*?(?=\s\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s%)""".r.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
    val action = """((?<=:\s)\w{4,10}(?=\s\w{2})|(?<=\w\s)(\w{7,9})(?=\s[f]))""".r.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
    val protocol = """(?<=[\w:]\s)(\w+)(?=\s[cr])""".r.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
    val connection_id = """(?<=\w\s)(\d+)(?=\sfor)""".r.findAllIn(x).mkString(",")
    val ips = """(?<=[\d\w][:\s])(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?=\/\d+|\z| \w)""".r.findAllIn(x).mkString("|")
    val ports = """(?<=\d/)(\d{1,6})(?=\z|[\s(])""".r.findAllIn(x).mkString("|")

    val logObject = logValues(time_stamp, action, protocol, connection_id, ips, ports)

    return logObject
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your current regex, which would match all needed values?

Comment: If you are using groups, you should be able to have the indexed or named group supposed to match the missing portion returning `null`, when invoking the relevant `Matcher#group` method. It all depends on your implementation.

Comment: I am trying to simplify now: you seem to want to get `connection_id:` to return matches in both cases, right? So, all you need is `"""connection_id\s*:\s*(\d*)"""` and the Group  1 var will be filled. `\d*` matches 0 or more digits, so it will return an empty string.

Comment: See a lookbehind version example - https://ideone.com/csivBv. Please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're compiling six different regex patterns and then submitting the the input string to the six different tests. A different approach is to create a single regex for the entire log line and extract the desired info via capture groups.

You'll have to tweak this since you know what parts are variant/invariant and I only have two example log lines to work with.

```
val logPattern =
  raw"^(.*)\s"                                    + // timestamp
  raw"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s%\S+\s" +
  raw"(\w+)?\s\w+\s"                              + // action
  raw"(\w+)?\s\w*\s*"                             + // protocol
  raw"(\d+)?\s.*outside:"                         + // connection ID
  raw"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/"      + // src IP
  raw"(\d+).*:"                                   + // src port
  raw"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/"      + // dst IP
  raw"(\d+)"                                        // dst port

val logRE = logPattern.r.unanchored  // only once
```

The upside: more efficient and everything is in one place. The downside: the whole pattern can fail if one section is incorrect. (Note: Compile the regex pattern only once. Not every time you pass in a new log line.)

The extraction is now more direct.

```
log_line match {
  case logRE(ts,act,ptcl,cid,sip,sprt,dip,dprt) =>
    LogValues(ts,act,ptcl,cid,s"$sip/$dip",s"$sprt/$dprt")
  case _ => /* log line doesn't fit pattern */
}
```

You'll note I made three fields optional: `action`, `protocol`, and `connection ID`. Optional capture groups that don't capture anything return `null` and while it's OK for `String` values to be `null`, it's not considered good practice. Much better to use `Option[String]` instead. And while we're at it, since the whole log line might fail the pattern recognition, let's make the return type optional as well.

```
case class LogValues( time_stamp    : String
                    , action        : Option[String]
                    , protocol      : Option[String]
                    , connection_id : Option[String]
                    , ips           : String
                    , ports         : String
                    )

log_Line match {
  case logRE(ts,act,ptcl,cid,sip,sprt,dip,dprt) =>
    Some(LogValues( ts
                  , Option(act)
                  , Option(ptcl)
                  , Option(cid)
                  , s"$sip/$dip"
                  , s"$sprt/$dprt" ))
  case _ => /* log line doesn't fit pattern */
    None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you're matching an optional group that doesn't exist you'll get a null for the group. I'd match like below and then wrap the potentially null value in an Option for type safety and proceed from there.

```
mshelton-mshelton@ val sampleRegex = """(\w+)-(\w+)?-(\w+)""".r
sampleRegex: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\w+)-(\w+)?-(\w+)
mshelton-mshelton@ val sampleRegex(a, b, c) = "aaa-bbb-ccc"
a: String = "aaa"
b: String = "bbb"
c: String = "ccc"
mshelton-mshelton@ val sampleRegex(a, b, c) = "aaa--ccc"
a: String = "aaa"
b: String = null
c: String = "ccc"
```

Comment: Check my regex, I used lookahead and lookbehind.